# Como posso simplificar requisições HTTP no React?

Tags: react, axios, react-hooks

Atualmente estou trabalhando em um projeto que possui módulos com múltiplas requisições a API. Analogamente, são frequentes os casos de requisições "ordenadas", isto é, que são realizadas na medida que  determinada condição é atendida. Desta forma, ao decorrer do trabalho pude perceber que as requisições estavam deixando o código excessivamente verboso, isto porque uma única requisição demanda de um bloco considerável de código.

**Exemplo do formato que estou utilizando atualmente:**

```
useEffect(() => {
    const cancelToken = axios.CancelToken.source();
    api
      .get(getUfs(), {
        cancelToken: cancelToken.token
      })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          const options = createOptions(res.data, {
            label: "sigla",
            value: "sigla"
          });
          selectUfs.setOptions(options);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => null);
    return () => cancelToken.cancel();
  }, []);
```

Considerando apenas uma requisição no componente este modelo não trouxe nenhum problema, entretanto, na medida que o número de requisições aumenta a legibilidade do código é prejudicada. Em minhas buscas por soluções encontrei poucas alternativas, algumas excessivamente complexas, outras que funcionam apenas em determinada situação, no entanto, a que me pareceu mais atrativa foi a criação de um **hook** customizado para lidar com as requisições. De forma geral busco diminuir a quantidade de código preservando as funcionalidades. Se alguém conhecer uma forma mais eficiente de lidar com as requisições e quiser compartilhar, desde de já agradeço :)

Comment: Jovem, me tire só uma dúvida dessas modernidades, esse código roda no servidor ou tá rodando no frontend? Mas respondendo sua pergunta, isso parece ser uma forma de Callback Hell, acho que o que resolve isso são promises do JavaScript ou algo similar, tipo fluent interface, pesquise a respeito que devem atender.

Comment: Olá, primeiramente gostaria de agradecer pela sua resposta. Bom, este código esta rodando no frontend e no momento não estou tendo nenhum problema relacionado a Callback Hell... Nesse caso estou apenas buscando encontrar uma forma mais simplificada de fazer as requisições a fim de tornar o código menos verboso e melhorar a legibilidade.

Comment: O pessoal chama de Callback Hell no JavaScript quando as callbacks se aninham e o código fica ruim de acompanhar de uma forma parecida como está a legibilidade do seu. Não sei se é o seu caso mas está parecendo. Quanto a rodar no front-end, não sei se é o mais adequado, penso que uma sequência de chamadas HTTP assim meio com comportamento transacional deveria rodar no servidor. Se fosse um app móvel por exemplo a rede móvel mais instável poderia prejudicar. Mas também sei lá. O pessoal sempre fala tão bem de React, deve ser uma forma válida de fazer.